# Using foreach with ASP.NET view engine inside a ASP: Repeater is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have a ASP: Repeater, I need to use a foreach loop using ASP.NET view engine

But I have ran into a issue.

Here is the code inside the repeater:

```
           <%# cart = (CartDTO)Container.DataItem %>

                      <% foreach (var item in cart.Products)
                       { %> 
                        <p><%= item.Title %></p>
                      <% }%>
```

The problem here is that nothing renders out. I have found the issue. I have to use `<%#` instead of `<%=` that will render it. But the issues is that <%# does not work in a ASP: Repeater. Item becomes "Cannot resolve "Item" symbol.

Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of data that is binded to repeater. Something in JSON will be great so we can run in on our machines. Further post the entire markup of the repeater

Comment: it is better practice to do your binding on code behind as you have more control on the data at the server end and also performance improves as databinding on the client end causes reflection and rebinding. - server side should be use for data binding and also makes it less tight coupled than on the UI/view/aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think repeater will easily understand such snippet inside the item template. In general C# code in ASP.NET page markup should not be used for things more complicated than "output this value to the page".

You better off creating a nested repeater for such task:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((CartDTO)Container.DataItem).Products %>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p> <%# Eval("Title") %></p>
    </ITemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```